Reload Image Given Through Command Line Input Raspberry Pi
I have created a python program that generates an image of sports scores and then sends the image to my Raspberry Pi to be displayed using a scrolling image program on matrix LED panels. I can run the image scrolling program using the command line with a command like this:
sudo ./image-scroller.py --I Game_Image_Combined.ppm where image-scroller.py is obviously the program used to display and scroll the image on the led panels and the Game_Image_Combined.ppm is the large image file the will scroll.
My question is how can I automate this to rerun the command every minute or so. A new image file will be sent to the Pi every minute but I need a way to restart the command automatically through the command line or some other method. Ideally, I would love to automate the process so it automatically resets once the image has finished scrolling. This is difficult because depending on the amount of games for each day the size of the image and thus the time it takes to complete a full scrolling loop changes on a day to day basis. Thanks for your help and taking the time to check out my issue! The following is code from the image-scroller.py script.
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from samplebase import SampleBase
from PIL import Image


class ImageScroller(SampleBase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageScroller, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.parser.add_argument("-i", "--image", help="The image to display", default="../../../examples-api-use/runtext.ppm")

    def run(self):
        if not 'image' in self.__dict__:
            self.image = Image.open(self.args.image).convert('RGB')
        self.image.resize((self.matrix.width, self.matrix.height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        double_buffer = self.matrix.CreateFrameCanvas()
        img_width, img_height = self.image.size

        # let's scroll
        xpos = 0
        while True:
            xpos += 1
            if (xpos > img_width):
                xpos = 0

            double_buffer.SetImage(self.image, -xpos)
            double_buffer.SetImage(self.image, -xpos + img_width)

            double_buffer = self.matrix.SwapOnVSync(double_buffer)
            time.sleep(0.01)

# Main function
# e.g. call with
#  sudo ./image-scroller.py --chain=4
# if you have a chain of four
if __name__ == "__main__":
    image_scroller = ImageScroller()
    if (not image_scroller.process()):
        image_scroller.print_help() 

I have done some research into how to run a script automatically on a raspberry pi but I am not sure how to stop and then restart the script.

If you're looking to run a CLI command on a routine basis, I would recommend looking into [cron-jobs][https://cronitor.io/guides/cron-jobs]. This is an linux based utility that allows you to set up commands to run on a regular cadence. The only other thing you'll have to worry about is terminating the existing process. You could come up with a bash script to find the PID of the running process, or you could set up a timeout in your PY script that exits the program after a minute (perhaps by breaking from your while True: loop after a minute has passed)
